# jquery mobile scrollview - how to show hidden content and stop scrollview from snapping back to inital position

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, scrollview

I'm working on a JQM project using the scrollview plugin.

I have everything set-up, and scrollview is working. However, the "hidden" content to be scrolled doesn't load completely and the scrollview always snaps back to its initial position.

Here is the link to an example:

[example](http://www.franckreich.de/3/members/m.html)

Any clues how to tame scrollview?

Thanks!

Comment: not yet. Haven`t tried for a while, because of other stuff to do. I will be sitting back on it shortly. Any clues?

Comment: I ran into the same issues. It seems to work but when I release it scrolls back to the top. I hope I find the answer.

Comment: It's just a guess (I don't have time to investigate), but it might help - take a look at jqm's silentScroll method and see if it can be used to restore the position. [Your example doesn't seem to work in FF]

Comment: Thanks. But it was my fault assingning wrong CSS and data-scroll attributes. See below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I found out why it's not working. You need something like this for it to work:

```
<div class="wrapper" data-scroll="x" style="width: 100px; overflow-x:scroll;">
   <div class="element2Bscrolled" style="width: 800px;">some loooong text</div>
</div>
```

Working example: [here](http://www.franckreich.de/3/members/m2.html).

In my original post I just mixed up the elements.