# jquery.mobile.scrollview.js: avoid that scrolling bounces back to original position

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, scroll, scrollview

I am using scrollview to scroll an dynamically generated table wrapped in a div in my app, so i can not apply a fixed height to the div wrapper. I got it scrolling, but the scrolling content is bouncing back to the start position. Dos anybody has an idea how to do this properly, so that I can move the content and it stays there, where I scrolled it?

I was googling since several days to find a solution. Hopefully somebody here encountered the same problem and solved it.

Comment: I found an [answer to a very similar question][1] which helped me solving the problem.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109947/jquery-mobile-scrollview-how-to-show-hidden-content-and-stop-scrollview-from-s

Answer (score 3):

There is the option `scrollMethod` set by default to `translate`. Set it up to `scroll` to cancel the bounce (moreover, the performance will be better on mobile).